# Iterate div ids and ahref #link inside a while in php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I am having this issue while i modify my wordpress theme.
I am displaying a post query of movies info. using while, and therefore i have a link to call a div that contains the trailer of each movie. However, when i click any of the links it only opens the trailer of the first movie. Meaning, i have to iterate trough ids to have an unique id for each post/movie and this iteration should be done in the a href and the div id.

```
<?php query_posts( $args ); ?><?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="#modal">Trailer</a>
<div id="modal" class="modalmask">
<?php /* i call trailer iframe */ ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

¿How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php query_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <a href="#modal-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Trailer</a>
   <div id="modal-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="modalmask">
      <?php /* i call trailer iframe */ ?>
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: This works. Of course i've added the $ to the variable. So simple, couldn't see it. Got to practice dammit! Thanks!!

Comment: Altough the problem is solved, did u edit ur answer? the $i process is gone from it hehe!

Comment: Now i realize that u quit the iteration and only ask for the id. That's better! thanks.